# return octuple patterns from nested sublists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

How can I create patterns desribed below from python lists or if easier from numpy Arrays.

Let's say I have such a list of lists:

```
[
[a,a,0,a],
[0,b,0,b],
[c,0,c,c]
]
```

the returned list should Loop through the nested lists in traversal order (element 1 of sublist 1, element 1 of sublist 2 and so on) but create always octuple list sizes.

```
[
 [a,0,c,0,0,0,0,0],
 [a,b,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,c,0,0,0,0,0],
 [a,b,c,0,0,0,0,0]
]
```

In the next example I have another sublist in a sublist:

```
[
 [a,a,    0,   a],
 [0,[b,b],0,   b],
 [c,c    ,c,[c,c]]
]
```

The resulting pattern should be a traversal again. the rule here is to handle element one of those lists in sublists the same, but for element two of those sublists consider only elements which have those depth and spend them there own octuple pattern.

```
[
 [a,0,c, 0,0,0,0,0],
 [a,b,c, 0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,b,0, 0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,c, 0,0,0,0,0],
 [a,b,c, 0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,c, 0,0,0,0,0],
]
```

Another example:

```
[
 [a    ,a     ] ,
 [b    ,[b,b,b]],
 [[c,c],0     ]
]

[
[a,b,c,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,c,0,0,0,0,0],
[a,b,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,b,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,b,0,0,0,0,0,0]
]
```

If sublists have different length:

```
[
 [a,0],
 [b,[b,b],b]
]

[
 [a,b,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,b,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,b,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,b,0,0,0,0,0,0]
]
```

Can someone show me an approach how to handle the traversals and handle those exceptions with the nested lists and returning always octuples?
Is there maybe another Container or structure which make those patterns easier to receive?

thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a limit to the number of times you have a nested list inside nested lists ? Is [ [a, [ [ a, [ 0, 1 ] ], 5 ] ], [a, b]] a possible input ?

Comment: when you mean with number how many sublists can be in a sublist then it's variable. The depth has a maximum.  So inside the outer list container [ ] Holding all the sublists [[sublist1], [sublist2],...] where a sublist could contain either simple values: ..[a,a,a] or e.g. [[c,c],[c,c,c]] or mixed. So each sublist has either no depth or level one or mixed [b, [b,b,b,b,b,b], [b,b]]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following is my approach to the problem:

```
from functools import reduce

original = [
    ['a', 0],
    ['b', ['b', 'b'], 'b']
]

max_len = max([len(i) for i in original])
padded_original = [
    (i + [0] * max_len)[:max_len]
    for i in original
]
print(padded_original)
# [['a', 0, 0], ['b', ['b', 'b'], 'b']]

max_col_lens = reduce(
    lambda a, b: [max(a[i], b[i]) for i in range(len(a))],
    [
        [len(xi) if isinstance(xi, list) else 1 for xi in x]
        for x in padded_original
    ]
)
print(max_col_lens)
# [1, 2, 1]


original_transformed = [
    reduce(
        lambda a, b: a + b,
        [(item + [0] * size)[:size] for (item, size) in row]
    ) for row in [
        zip(
            [xi if isinstance(xi, list) else [xi] for xi in x],
            max_col_lens
        ) for x in padded_original
    ]
]
print(original_transformed)
# [['a', 0, 0, 0], ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b']]

result_list = [
    [0 for i in range(8)]
    for j in range(
        sum(
            reduce(
                lambda a, b: [max(a[i], b[i]) for i in range(len(a))],
                [
                    [len(xi) if isinstance(xi, list) else 1 for xi in x]
                    for x in padded_original
                ]
            )
        )
    )
]
print(result_list)
# [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

# rotating transformed_original_transformed
for i in range(len(original_transformed)):
    for j in range(len(original_transformed[i])):
        result_list[j][i] = original_transformed[i][j]

print(result_list)
# [['a', 'b', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 'b', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 'b', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 'b', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: This does not answers OP's question. This works only with the first use_case

Comment: Hi Iprakashv, thanks for your code. I still try to figure out how it works (list comprehensions still confusing for me) but right now I can say that it works. Thanks a lot for your support. I will mark as completed when I am done with testing.

Comment: Oh, I will try to simplify it further in my next edit. Will post after sometime.